# grub loader error

Tags: 12.04, installation

i bought a laptop which has windows 7 as an os but i want to try ubuntu so i install ubuntu in a new drive which was done well so i don't like the two os and i deleted the drive which contains windows 7 but when i restart my laptop i got grub loader error and i again install ubuntu 12.04 in that drive which i have formated now i have the 2 os which is same and again i deleted a ubuntu drive again the same error came so again i install ubuntu in that drive so can you guys help me to remove the another ubuntu without that error

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to *disk* by saying *drive* here in "so again i install ubuntu in that drive", I think you are repeatedly installing Ubuntu again and again by creating unnecessary partitions for each installation.

Instead of doing this, I suggest you to delete the former Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sdaX`, where `X` can be 1, 2, 3..etc), and then Install Ubuntu on the same partition (of course, in the Live Ubuntu session). You can access to this advanced partitioning, by selecting *Something else* at the partition selection stage for your Ubuntu.

Alternatively, you could use grub rescue process without installing Ubuntu again and again. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/61218) is a very good one I think. Note that, after rescuing Grub2, you need to delete the obsolete Ubuntu installation. You can do that by using gparted. It can be installed with the command

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

in a terminal. After installation, open it and detect the older obsolete Ubuntu partition and delete it or format it to use the spaces.

It is highly recommended to use these two commands after manipulating partitions in Ubuntu. So, after you have done with gparted, open a terminal and use these

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: error occurs
sushil@sushil-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: no signature.

/usr/sbin/grub-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.